# Use Datepicker date as input to another view

Tags: swiftui

Goal : use of selected date components of a datepicker as an input to a view where quotes from an external website are fetched.

Tried these approaches : using qDate:Date as parameter to init() for QuotesViewModel and QuotesView - but this approach seems to work only if parameter is struct/class.
Also tried to use @Binding variable but with no success.

Is there an elegant solution?

```
struct HomeView: View {

    @State var qDate = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
            DatePicker("", selection: $qDate, displayedComponents: .date)             
            QuotesView()
    }
}


struct QuotesView : View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: QuotesViewModel 
    
    init() {
        self.vm = QuotesViewModel()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
            Text(vm.quote ?? "")
    }
}

class QuotesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var quote: String?

// Use Datepicker qDate components to create URL to fetch quote from external website.  
 
}
```

Comment: Binding should work, could you possibly send what code you had when trying Binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a value into a view using the init, any external change to that value will result in the view being rebuilt:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @State var qDate = Date()

    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("", selection: $qDate, displayedComponents: .date)
        QuotesView(quoteDate: qDate)
    }
}

struct QuotesView: View {
    let viewModel: QuotesViewModel

    init(quoteDate: Date) {
        self.viewModel = QuotesViewModel(quoteDate: quoteDate)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.quote)
    }
}

class QuotesViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var quote: String

    init(quoteDate: Date) {
        //... Your external service
        let quotes = ["Be yourself; everyone else is already taken.", "Try to be a rainbow in someone else's cloud."]
        self.quote = quotes.randomElement() ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: You could reduce some of the code by changing it to:
`QuotesView(viewModel: QuotesViewModel(quoteDate: qDate))`

That would save the init.